# php.ini is not read after upgrading to PHP 5.6.25 from RHSC on RHEL7 with SELinux. How to debug?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, selinux, php.ini, rhel7

Configuration: I run a web server with RHEL7 with the SELinux kernel module and php-fpm.  By default, RHEL7 ships with PHP 5.4. This version of PHP is too old for my software, so I've upgraded to PHP 5.6.25 from RHSC.

Before upgrading, everything was working as expected.

When I run the upgraded php from the CLI, everything works fine.  For instance, I've changed the value for `upload_max_filesize` (on line 810) from 2M (the default) to 8M, and this change appears as expected when I query the PHP settings from the CLI:

```
php -v
php 5.6.25 (cli) ...
php -i | fgrep upload_max_filesize
upload_max_filesize => 8M => 8M
```

However, *after* the upgrade, it looks like `php.ini` is no longer read by read by Apache when Apache is restarted.  I.e.: the changes to `php.ini` have no effect (*all* values, including the value for `upload_max_filesize` stay at their defaults).

I've created a web-page to debug this, it contains the following snippet of PHP code:

```
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();
echo '<p>Loaded php.ini: <code>' . $inipath . '</code>.</p>';
$contents = file($inipath);
if ($contents) {
  echo '<p>Line 810: ' . $contents[810] . '.</p>';
} else {
  echo '<p>Unable to read php.ini file.</p>';
}
echo '<p>ini_get(): upload_max_filesize = ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . '.</p>';
```

It outputs:

```
Loaded php.ini: /etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini.
Line 810:  upload_max_filesize = 8M.
ini_get(): upload_max_filesize = 2M.
```

I.e. the path to the `php.ini` used by the webserver is `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini`, and it sets `upload_max_filesize` to 8M on line 810.  Still, the value returned when I call `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` is the default.  (Yes, I *have* restarted Apache).

There are nothing that  sets `upload_max_filesize` in other `.ini` files or in `.htaccess` (I've searched extensively).

I have now exhausted my options for debugging, and hope for answers that will suggest how I can crack this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out at last!

It turns out that restarting Apache (httpd) is not enough to make changes to `php.ini` take effect with this particular configuration. You also need to restart the FastCGI Process Manager.  The following command resolved it:

```
sudo systemctl restart rh-php56-php-fpm.service
```

Comment: To change the PHP configuration when using php-fpm, you don't need to restart Apache at all, only PHP.